# Pass a local param to a global param in XSLT using Java

Tags: java, xslt, parameter-passing

Inside my For-each loop, two columns, Division (string) and Paydate (date) are included as columns.

Once the For-each loop is done, I write an offset line so that the Journal Entry I am creating is in balance.  However, I need to include the Division and Paydate on the offset line.  Since these two values only "exist" inside the For-each loop, they are unavailable to me on the offset line.

Does anyone have experience using the Java params function (MSXSL version) where they have passed a param from inside the For-each to a global param?

I tried to update a global variable inside the For-each, first by trying to define it globally and locally and then by defining the global variable with the local.  I have since learned that XSL variables are not variables (sorry, I'm an old RPG coder, this is gnu stuff to me).

```
<!-- Global param -->
<xsl:param name = "DiviG"/>

<!-- Choose to populate local variable -->
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="PayGroupxRef='11DD_B' or PayGroupxRef='11DD_Hourly'">
<xsl:variable name = "Divi">504</xsl:variable>
</xsl:when>
```

There is only one PayGroupxRef and PayPeriodDate per run.  I need these two values to be on each line of the For-each loop as well as the offset line.

```
Division    PayDate     Amount
504     09/06/19    +10.00
504     09/06/19    +20.00
504     09/06/19    -30.00
```

The XML input is generated by a separate function that I have no control over.  It is Payroll data for a pay period with a limited number of tags I have access to, e.g. PayGroupxRef is the xRef value defined in the Pay Group table, Pay Date is the token payrun_pay_date.

The output is that I need PayGroupxRef, translated via the case statement, on each line of the extract as well as the Payrun_Pay_Date.  Once each record from input has been process, I then need to write one additional line that has the negative amount of the summed amounts from the For-each loop (apologies for the gauche terminology) with  the PayGroupxRef and PayDate as well.  The sum piece works fine, it's the last two pieces I am missing.

Abbreviated XSLT Code:

```
<!-- Headers -->
<xsl:text>Divi,</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>Acc Date,</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#x0D;&#x0A;</xsl:text>

<!-- Details -->
<xsl:for-each select="Export/Record[Amount!=0] and AccrualType='AC'">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="PayGroupxRef='11DD_B' or    PayGroupxRef='11DD_Hourly'">`
        <xsl:text>504</xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="Divi">504</xsl: variable>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="PayGroupxRef='11DI_B'">
        <xsl:text>XXX</xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="Divi">XXX</xsl: variable>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="PayGroupxRef='11DF_B' or PayGroupxRef='11DC_B'">
        <xsl:text>510</xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="Divi">510</xsl: variable>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="PayGroupxRef='11DH_W' or PayGroupxRef='11DD_B'">
        <xsl:text>40R</xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="Divi">40R</xsl: variable>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="PayGroupxRef='11DB_B' or PayGroupxRef='11DA_B'">
        <xsl:text>50A</xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="Divi">50A</xsl: variable>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="PayGroupxRef='11DE_B'">
        <xsl:text>500</xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="Divi">500</xsl: variable>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>???</xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="Divi">???</xsl: variable>
    </xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="PayDate"/>
<xsl:text>&#x0D;&#x0A;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>

<!-- Write the offset line -->
<xsl:copy-of select="Divi"/>
<xsl:value-of select="PayDate"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can see valiable $Divi in the For-each loop but if I try an use it outside the loop (with apologies if I use incorrect terminology) it says $Divi isn't defined.

Comment: I suggest you post a [mcve] showing the XML input, your current XSLT code and the expected output.

Comment: Why don't you store the first result (of the two "loops")  in a variable and then access it twice, once to output the table with the columns, the second time to compute the offset line? Even possible in XSLT 1 if you make use of `exsl:node-set` or similar but as you use Java you have access to XSLT 3 with Saxon 9.9 or 9.8 and can easily do it without an extension function.

Comment: If you compute a sum of various items or records, I understand that you get a single value for all the records processeed. However, I don't understand how you determine the `Divi` value for the line with the sum, is that the last value you processed in the `for-each`? Or where does that value come from if you have processed several records with different values?

Comment: Good morning Martin.  That is my issue, I need the last value of Divi (there can be only one...Divi per payrun) and the PayRunDate from the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You're obviously struggling with the functional programming paradigm used by XSLT: you're thinking in terms of "loops" and "updates", and you've forgotten your elementary school maths, where in a formula like `area=length*width`, `length` and `width` are called variables because they are different for different rectangles, not because the rectangle is changing shape while you do the calculation.

The problem now is that you've explained the problem in terms of procedural code for getting the answer (actually, in terms of broken code that doesn't get the answer), not in terms of the input, the output, and their relationship. Reverse engineering non-working code to a high-level statement of the problem is not easy, and shouldn't be necessary. Show us the input, show us the output, explain how they relate to each other, and you've provided a functional description of the problem that will usually translate very naturally to a functional solution.

Comment: Yes, I am obviously struggling with XSLT.  I will work on providing the code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the approach I had in mind with my first suggestion, is to use XML as an intermediary store doing e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="lines-rtf">
<xsl:for-each select="Export/Record[Amount!=0] and AccrualType='AC'">
  <record>
    <divi>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="PayGroupxRef='11DD_B' or    PayGroupxRef='11DD_Hourly'">`
        <xsl:text>504</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="PayGroupxRef='11DI_B'">
        <xsl:text>XXX</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="PayGroupxRef='11DF_B' or PayGroupxRef='11DC_B'">
        <xsl:text>510</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="PayGroupxRef='11DH_W' or PayGroupxRef='11DD_B'">
        <xsl:text>40R</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="PayGroupxRef='11DB_B' or PayGroupxRef='11DA_B'">
        <xsl:text>50A</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="PayGroupxRef='11DE_B'">
        <xsl:text>500</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
 </xsl:choose>
</divi>
  <paydate>
    <xsl:value-of select="PayDate"/>
  </paydate>
 </record>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Now, in most XSLT 1.0 processors, that variable has a value of type result tree fragment and to allow you to use XPath on it you need to use an extension function first, most XSLT 1 processors support

```
<xsl:variable name="lines" select="exsl:node-set($lines-rtf)" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"/>
```

for some (notably MSXML) you however need to use a similar extension function in a proprietary namespace specific to that particular vendor or processor.

To output your summary you can then use `<xsl:value-of select="$lines/record[last()]/divi"/>` and to output the lines you run the variable through templates or another `for-each`.

Whether you need the intermediary XML I am not quite sure as I haven't seen the initial XML input and therefore I am not sure whether a single selection on that suffices to extract the stuff you need. But in general, if you want to store more than one value, you can use XML to do that and then, in XSLT 1 only with the help of the extension function, you can process that intermediary XML as needed further.

Things are a lot easier and compact to write in XSLT 2/3 where you have a more powerful `xsl:value-of` with the `separator` attribute, the `string-join` function, user-defined functions.

So if you are on Java where Saxon 9 is in any case better developed and maintained than the Xalan XSLT 1 processor built into the Oracle JRE, you should consider moving to XSLT 2/3 with Saxon 9 and some things cost less lines of code and less headache. Although the adaption from procedural to declarational/functional programming is a step you need to make in any case.

Comment: Good afternoon Martin, thanks for providing this approach.  I tried it in our environment and something about it upsets our validation tool.  I will try and figure out what and let you know what happens.